# Bind a set of animations to window load in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to run some lines of code when my page finishes loading in jQuery. I want to specify the timings precisely, and I can't do that right now.

What I want:

```
load({
    //Load animations 
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simple, just some syntax:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    //Load animations         
});
```